# Wordpress: Javascript redirect issue using window.location when called from home page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So, I have a plugin that redirects users, using jQuery/Javascript, to a specified page as follows:

```
window.location.href = window.location.hostname + '/index.php/searchresults-gw/'
```

When the plugin is referenced from any page other than the home page, `192.1.0.2/pagename/` for example, then the user is correctly redirected to `192.1.0.2/index.php/searchresults-gw/`.

But when the same plugin is referenced from the home page (192.1.0.2), the url tries to resolve to `192.1.0.2/192.1.0.2/index.php/searchresults-gw/`

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.location.href = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/index.php/searchresults-gw/'

Comment: @TheoG Do you like to accept it as a correct answer?

Comment: I actually that voting up handled that. but it's done now.